# How to express this concept without dynamic dispatch?

Tags: rust, dynamic-dispatch

I am building a simulation (the coding equivalent of a model train set). It is a simulated economy with various economic agents interacting with each other. The main mode of interaction between economic agents is a transaction. At each "tic", each agent generates a list of zero or more proposed transactions (such as buying food). At each "toc" all the counter-parties process the proposed transactions that have been targeted at them in random order so that no biases are introduced. In these snippets a proposed transaction is represented as a `u32`.

My goal is to simulate as many of these economic agents as possible so performance is key. I am new to rust (or any kind of low level language for that matter) and my understanding from reading the rust book is if I want maximum performance then use "zero cost abstractions" and avoid dynamic dispatch.

So with that out the way I have come up with the following 3 approaches.

**Option 1**

```
trait EconomicAgent {
    fn proposed_transactions(&self) -> Vec<u32>;
}

struct Person {
    health:f64,
    energy:f64,
    nutrition:f64,
    money:f64,
    food:f64
}

impl EconomicAgent for Person {
    fn proposed_transactions(&self) -> Vec<u32> {
        vec![1, 2, 3]
    }
}

struct FoodStore {
    money:f64,
    food:f64
}

impl EconomicAgent for FoodStore {
    fn proposed_transactions(&self) -> Vec<u32> {
        vec![4, 5, 6]
    }
}
```

A person and a food store are different types that implement the `EconomicAgent` trait. I can then iterate over a vector of trait objects to get a list of proposed transactions. Each call is dynamically dispatched, I believe.

**Option 2**

```
enum EconomicAgent2 {
    Person(Person),
    FoodStore(FoodStore)
}

impl EconomicAgent2 {
    fn proposed_transactions(&self) -> Vec<u32> {
        match self{
            EconomicAgent2::Person(person) => person.proposed_transactions(),
            EconomicAgent2::FoodStore(food_store) => food_store.proposed_transactions()
        }
    }
}
```

Here, an `EconomicAgent` is not a trait, but rather an enum and, well you can see how it works.

**Option 3**

```
const HEALTH_INDEX : u8 = 0;
const ENERGY_INDEX : u8 = 1;
const NUTRITION_INDEX : u8 = 2;
const MONEY_INDEX : u8 = 3;
const FOOD_INDEX : u8 = 4;

enum EconomicAgentTag {
    Person,
    FoodStore
}
struct EconomicAgent3 {
    tag: EconomicAgentTag,
    resources:[f64; 5],
    proposed_transactions: Box<fn(&EconomicAgent3) -> Vec<u32>>
}

fn new_person() -> EconomicAgent3 {
    EconomicAgent3 {
        tag: EconomicAgentTag::Person,
        resources: [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
        proposed_transactions: Box::new(|_| vec![1, 2, 3])
    }
}

fn new_food_Store() -> EconomicAgent3 {
    EconomicAgent3 {
        tag: EconomicAgentTag::FoodStore,
        resources: [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
        proposed_transactions: Box::new(|_| vec![4, 5, 6])
    }
}
```

Here an economic agent is more abstract representation.

Now imagine that there a many different types of economic agents (banks, mines, farms, clothing stores etc). They all interact by proposing and accepting transactions. Option 1 seems to suffer from dynamic dispatch. Option 2 seems to be my own version of dynamic dispatch via a match expression so is probably no better, right? Option 3 seems like it should be the most performant but does not really allow much cognitive ease on the part of the programmer.

So finally the questions:

1. Clearly dynamic dispatch is involved in option 1. What about options 2 and 3?
2. Which is expected to be most performant? Note I am not really in a position to do testing as the full idea (only on paper right now) is obviously more complex than these snippets and the choice now will affect the entire structure for the whole project.
3. What would be an idiomatic choice here?

Comment: All of your examples use runtime-dependent function execution and therefore dynamic dispatch. If the proper choice of function depends on user input or can't be hardcoded for every code location then there is no way of static dispatch, in no language. For the other case, you'd need C++-style templates with inefficient code bloat. Dynamic Dispatch is often an optimization, not a problem. Option 2 implements it explicitly via control structure which could be slower. Without having profiled the code, forcing static dispatch is premature optimization because the difference is very small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your options use dynamic dispatch or branches in one way or another to call the right function for each element. The reason is that you are mixing all the agents into a single place, which is where the different performance penalties come from (not just the indirect calls or branches, but also cache misses etc.).

Instead, for a problem like this, you want to separate the different "agents" into separate, independent "entities". Then, to reuse code, you will want to factor out "components" for which subsets of them are iterated by "systems".

This is what is usually called an "Entity-Component-System" (ECS) of which there are many models and implementations. They are typically used by games and other simulations.

If you search for ECS you will find many questions, articles and so on about it and the different approaches.

Comment: I like the idea of ECS. I have heard of it but never really looked into it. Will certainly do so for this. Can you elaborate on how option 3 uses dynamic dispatch to call it's method? Seems like it is "set in stone" from creation, no?

Comment: @ChechyLevas Glad to help! In Option 3 you have got a tag that you will have to discriminate upon, which means a branch. That is basically the same the compiler does for you with a tagged union (Option 2). (Then there is also the boxed `fn`, which means an indirection, but that can be avoided calling a pure function, so it is not the main drawback of the approach).

Comment: I would note that the performance difference between function pointer (Option 1 and 3) and branch (Option 2) are likely significant because function pointers are a barrier to inlining whereas branches are not -- bundling them all into a single bucket is not helpful.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Option 3 is a branch too since it is the same as a tagged union, not a function pointer (OP uses a function pointer there too, but that can be avoided). "*bundling them all*" While in many cases branches win (few cases, small callees with opt. opportunities, etc.), I'd say it is a pitfall to declare a victory in the general case. So I prefer to avoid claiming one is faster than the other (but I don't bundle them together either). On the other hand, packing data, minimizing cache misses, ECS, etc. are definitely a win (as you know), specially when handling many agents.

Answer (score 3):

#### What is Dynamic Dispatch?

[Dynamic Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) is usually reserved to indirect function calls, ie function calls which occurs via a function pointer.

In your case, both Option 1 and Option 3 are cases of dynamic dispatch:

- Traits use a virtual table, which is a table of function pointers.
- `fn(...) -> ...` is a function pointer.

#### What is the performance penalty of Dynamic Dispatch?

At run-time, there is little to no difference between a regular function call and a so-called virtual call:

- Indirect function calls *can* be predicted, there's a special predictor for them in your CPU.
- The cost of the function call is mostly saving/restoring registers, which happen in both cases.

The performance penalty is more insidious, it happens at *compile-time*.

The mother of optimizations is *inlining*, which essentially copy/paste the body of the function being called right at the call-site. Once a function is inlined, many other optimization passes can go to town on the (combined) code. This is especially lucrative on very small functions (a getter), but can also be quite beneficial on larger functions.

An indirect function call, however, is opaque. There are many candidate functions, and thus the optimizer cannot perform inlining... nipping many potential optimizations in the bud. Devirtualization is sometimes available -- the compiler deducing which function(s) can be called -- but should not be relied on.

#### Which Option to choose?

Among those presented: **Option 2**!

The main advantage of Option 2 is that there is no indirect function calls. In both branches of your `match`, the compiler has a known type for the receiver of the method and can therefore inline the method if suitable, enabling all the optimizations.

#### Is there better?

With an open-design, an Array of Structs is a better way to structure the system, mostly avoiding branch misprediction:

```
EconomicAgents {
    Person(Vec<Person>),
    FoodStore(Vec<FoodStore>),
}
```

This is the core design of the ECS solution proposed by [@Acorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62086004/147192).

*Note: as noted by @Acorn in comments, Array of Structs also is close to optimal cache wise -- no indirection, very little padding between elements.*

Going with a full ECS is a trickier proposition. Unless you have dynamic entities -- Person/FoodStores are added/removed during the runs -- I would not bother. ECS are helpful for dynamism, but have to choose a trade-off between various characteristics: do you want faster add/remove, or faster iteration? Unless you need all their features, they will likely add their own overhead due to trade-offs that do not match your needs.

Comment: "*mostly avoiding branch misprediction*" The main advantage in most systems like this is about maximizing cache hits and minimizing misspent cache space. Avoiding branch mispredictions (or indirect calls) and letting the compiler inline are both important wins, no doubt at all, but the CPU/mem gap is too big, so the former is usually the big topic for many simulations.

Comment: @Acorn That's a good point. In the OP's example both items have the same size, but in practice a variant often wastes space. Inlining/Optimization's importance will depend on the actual operation -- summing `Person::Wallet::amount` for example would benefit a lot, whilst a complicated method call would not really.

Answer (score 1):

## How to avoid dynamic dispatch?

You could go with option 1 and instead of having vector of trait objects, keep each type in its own vector and iterate them individually. It is not nice solution, so...

## Instead...

Choose whichever option allows you to model your simulation best and don't worry about the const of dynamic dispatch. The overhead is small. There are other things that will impact the performance more, such as allocating new `Vec` for every call.

The main cost of dynamic dispatch is indirect branch predictor making wrong guess. To help your cpu make better guesses, you may try to keep objects of the same type next to each other in the vector. For example sort it by type.

## Which one is idiomatic?

The option 1 has an issue that to store objects of different types into vector, you must go thru indirection. The easiest is to `Box` every object, but that means every access will have not only dynamic dispatch for the function, but will also have to follow extra pointer to get to the data.

The option 2 with enum is (in my opinion) more idiomatic - you have all your data together in continuous memory. But beware that the size of an enum is bigger (or equal) to its largest variant. So if you agents vary in size, it may be better to go with option 1.

Comment: The problem is not really the dynamic dispatch but the overall performance cost of such an approach. If I had to take a guess without knowing the system in particular, the cache misses are the biggest problem, not the dynamic dispatch (for a modern, non-embedded CPU, at least).

Comment: @Acorn Data cache or instruction cache? The option 2 for example has all data in continuous memory - no cache misses there. And it is just switching between few functions, which may stay cached unless they are too big.

Comment: Data cache. It is not really contiguous because there will be a lot of padding if the sizes differ significantly, which means misused cache. As for "few functions", you don't know that (unless I am missing something in the question). An ECS design scales way better for any number of kinds of agents.