# Is static dispatch "almost always" faster than boxed dyn trait dispatch?

Tags: rust, vtable, trait-objects, static-dispatch

The pros/cons of using static vs dynamic dispatch have been addressed in a few related questions, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49227286/1804173), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62085692/1804173), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75827353/dynamic-dispatch-alternative-in-rust).
From a performance perspective, it is intuitive to assume that [dynamic dispatch (via trait objects)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#trait-objects-perform-dynamic-dispatch) can be slower than static dispatch, and in certain situations it is a sensible performance optimization to use statically bounded static dispatch (as e.g. suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227483/1804173) or the [enum dispatch](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) crate, which simplifies this pattern). The enum dispatch crate states for instance:

> enum_dispatch transforms your trait objects into concrete compound types, increasing their method call speed up to 10x.

I'd assume there are basically two aspects that can make dynamic dispatch slower:

- Dynamic dispatch requires some sort of boxing, which introduces a memory indirection. This typically affects code that uses these trait objects in collections like `Vec`, because a vector of pointers is less cache efficient than a vector of enums.
- Dynamic dispatch prevents inlining functions calls.

This made me wonder if it is actually possible (or even likely?) to encounter situations where static dispatch is **slower** than dynamic dispatch?

For instance, what about a scenario in which the compiler wouldn't chose to inline the method call anyway, and the effect of the pointer redirection is negligible. In this case the performance in only determined by the dispatching itself. Dynamic dispatch uses a function pointer, so the complexity of the dispatching is independent of the number of possible dispatch branches. Static dispatching on the other hand uses some sort of `match` over an `enum` with `N` branches. How will the compiler handle that under that hood? Will it generate a potentially slow `O(N)` chain of comparisons to call the right method, or is it safe to assume that it can come up with optimized machine code that is still `O(1)`? Could using a vtable be actually faster in cases where the number of branches becomes really large?

---

Note: Of course, this question can and should be answered in each situation specifically by benchmarking the particular code. Nonetheless, I'd like to improve my mental model of what happens under the hood, and to develop a gut feeling whether *static dispatch is slower than dynamic dispatch* falls into either "almost never", "sometimes", "quite possible", ...

Comment: Of course it is possible to maneuver a benchmark where dynamic dispatch will be faster than static dispatch ([here's a completely made-up one](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=05709ac709faece76c8ad44f804b5bc3), where it is more than 2x faster). But on the general case, static dispatch will be faster, or at least not slower. There are instruction cache considerations, but those are hard to benchmark :)

Comment: I just [checked](https://godbolt.org/z/7nqrTeao3) that `match` uses the same optimisation as `switch`/`case` in C when the labels are adjacent: the multiple comparisons are turned into a jump, so no O(N) here.

Comment: There are other considerations than performance, though: `dyn Trait` is many times almost the speed of static dispatch, and is faster to compile.

Comment: The main source of slowdown for dynamic dispatch is actually the fact that it plays poorly with the instruction pipeline and branch predictor → dynamic dispatch can be faster on old or embedded CPU with short pipelines and without predictor. Especially if there are a lot of options to choose from, and so a lot of tests to select the correct function in the static dispatch case.

Comment: You can have a `Vec<dyn Trait>` and avoid the extra indirection by using stack based dynamic dispatch. `dyn Trait` is unsized, but `&dyn Trait` and `&muy dyn Trait` are both sized.

Comment: In general, match are compiled very efficiently. When possible, jump tables are used (O(1)); on very big matches, some compilers hash the various cases to still get a O(1) complexity; in other cases, a dichotomy is used to have O(lg n) complexity. All in all, it's extremely well optimized. However, the big difference is that with monomorphization, the code size can be much bigger, which can incur itself some time penalty due to poorer cache locality. In my opinion, static dispatch is "almost never" slower, but it has other disadvantages (no dynamic linking, longer compile time).

Comment: @MeetTitan `Vec<T>` requires `T: Sized` so `Vec<dyn Trait>` is not allowed.